# How to specifiy xticks in log-axis mode (tikzpicture) to be written in non-exponential format?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want to specify some xticks in a log-log plot (tikzpicture). This works fine, but they are always printed in exponential format (with basis 10). In general this is fine, but for one plot I would like to changes this. Is it possible?

Comment: Could you be more precise with what you want to achieve? I mean, is it about the ticks, or about the number format?

Comment: You can add e.g. `xticklabels={10,100,1000,10000,100000,100000}` to the options of your axis.

Comment: @T.Verron: The question is just about the number format of the ticks.

Comment: @Psirus: You could formulate this as an answer as it solves the problem! Thanks.

Comment: I bet there is a better, more automagical way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the option `log ticks with fixed point`.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{semilogxaxis}[
    unbounded coords=discard,
    log basis x=10,
    log ticks with fixed point
    ]
  \addplot coordinates {
  (0,1)
  (5,2)
  (10,3)
  (50,4)
  (100,5)
  (500,6)
  (1000,7)
  (5000,8)
  (10000,9)
  (100000,10)}
;
  \end{semilogxaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Example output]

If you need to specify it for one axis only, you can look at the answer to this question : [pgfplots: log ticks with fixed point on one logarithm axis](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44700/pgfplots-log-ticks-with-fixed-point-on-one-logarithm-axis) .