# Increasing the precision of integer tick labels on a logarithmic axis

Tags: pgfplots

I am trying to plot some data with on logarithmic axes. My x axis is labelled with integer numbers from the input data (`xtick=data`). I don't want to use scientific notation, so I added the `log ticks with fixed point` option. However, the tick labels are rounded and have a precision of only 3 digits.

[image: screenshot of example]

I have tried to solve this problem in 2 ways. First: changing the `x tick label style` with formatting options. See the example below.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{loglogaxis}[
        log ticks with fixed point,
        x tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed relative,/pgf/number format/precision=5},
        xtick=data,
        ]
            \addplot table[x=input,y=output] {
                input   output
                1   0.9
                16  4
                256 9
                4096    15
                65536   20
            };
    \end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

My second attempt was to recalculate the labels based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44724) and [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/287235/105511). This leads to some errors in the floating point calculation, since the example below results in the label '33442' instead of '33444'.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{loglogaxis}[
        log ticks with fixed point,
        log basis x=2,
        xticklabel={
            \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true}
            \pgfmathparse{2^\tick}
            \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed]{\pgfmathresult}
        },
        xtick=data,
        ]
            \addplot table[x=input,y=output] {
                input   output
                1   0.9
                16  4
                256 9
                4096    15
                33444   20
            };
    \end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

How can I solve this problem and display the numbers exactly as they are in my data?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Thomas!

Comment: Related (duplicate?): http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/287196/pgfplots-logarithmic-scale-showing-1020-insteead-of-1024

Comment: Thanks Jake, with the information in your answer there, I was able to solve my problem. One remark: the solution with recomputing the xticklabel is not very general, it does not apply to random/non regular input.
In case there is no answer in one day, I will delete this question, since it is indeed a duplicate.

Comment: @Thomas: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "it does not apply to random/non regular input". Could you edit your question to include an example where the linked answer fails?

Comment: @Jake: I have edited my question. In the meantime, I have also found another solution with `xticklabels from table`, which I will put in an answer.

Comment: @Thomas: Ah yes, I see! Good point, and good idea using `xticklabels from table` instead

Answer (score 2):

In this case, an easy solution is to use the attribute `xticklabels from table`, since the input data is in table format:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{loglogaxis}[
        log ticks with fixed point,
        xtick=data,
        xticklabels from table={data.dat}{input},
        ]
            \addplot table[x=input,y=output] {data.dat};
    \end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

where `data.dat` contains:

```
input   output
1   0.9
16  4
256 9
4096    15
33444   20
```

This gives the desired result:

[image]